# How does len count in list?

Tags: python, list

Ok I tried searching before I posted here. So don't shot me down if its already asked.

I want to know in Python's len function.

```
len([o,1]) -> 2 # Right
```

But how come in the following

```
len([a,[b,[c]]]) -> 2 # How?
```

Shouldn't it be 3??

I know this could be a very trivial question. So again please be patient with it.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `[a,[b,[c]]]` is a nested list.  The first element of the outer list is `a`, and the second is `[b,[c]]`.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't it be 3??

No because

```
[a,[b,[c]]]
```

is a two element list the first element is "a"

```
a
```

the second element is a list

```
[b,[c]]
```

(a list, itself len of 2 that contains yet another list of len 1).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. And coming to your question - `len` calculates the length of the list. So, in your example, the list has two elements `a` and another list `[b,[c]]`. If you were to find the length of the inner list it is again two since it has two elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you have a list with 2 elements (a and [b,[c]]).  If you wanted a list with 3 elements, you would use [a,b,c].